# boost async read/write fails with "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am (seemingly) randomly getting the error:

> "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

When using the `boost::asio::async_read_until` or `boost::asio::async_write` with a serial port.

Having the serial port declared as:

```
boost::asio::serial_port mSerialPort;
```

Following this error, I try to

```
try
{
    mSerialPort.cancel();
    mSerialPort.close();
}
catch(boost::system::system_error error)
{
    ;
}
```

Where one of them (not certain yet which) hangs and never returns, not even throwing an exception.

In general, what does this error mean ?

Has anybody encountered this problem ? Any direction in particular I should investigate ?

---

EDIT:

The serial port in question uses a USB emulator.

In regards to this [other SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961303/serialport-open-throws-ioexception-insufficient-system-resources-exist-to-co), specially the comment from Hans Passant, is it possible that this error is linked to the device driver ?  I use the same code with another hardware component and never got this behavior.

---

EDIT 2:

When searching on the web for this particular error message, often it is recommended to increase the paged pool memory as described here:

[Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312362)

Any sense in doing this in my case ?

Comment: Did you try to establish a correlation between the size of the data you are trying to transfer and the apparition of the error?

Comment: The size of the data is always the same, it's small commands and responses, size is around 4-10 chars longs.

Comment: What specific device and device driver are you using when you encounter this issue?

Comment: MCP2200 Microchip with updated device driver

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long, long time since I worked with serial ports on Windows, so take this reply with that in mind. Very historically, back in NT 4.0 days, most serial port drivers written off of the official NT kernel DDK guidelines couldn't do async i/o properly and would fail with your exact error from time to time and/or lock up. The solution was to only ever use synchronous i/o with serial i/o, that worked correctly. If the driver for your USB based serial port is sufficiently ancient originally, it may duplicate this problem.

I'd also make sure that you're using identical design patterns to known working ones. Try http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2012/12/13/boost-c-read-from-serial-port-with-timeout-example/ for an example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error commonly means that the main memory is maxed out and the system is allocating memory on swap until the HDD is full. Depending how long your program is running it could happen as the result of a memory leak.

However in your case something is happening at the driver level. You should check event viewer just in case something is reported there (assuming windows).

Were you able to get anything back from the serial port at all? Depending on your code, reading from the port will block indefinitely if nothing is sent back.

Things to try:

- Try reading one char at a time
- Async can be complicated due to callbacks, threading etc. Try synchronous.
- Was the device working with your code connected through the same emulator?
- Try increasing the buffer you are reading into
- Double check the protocol the device is using
- Double check baud rate

Here's great boost/asio resource (POSIX based but the general info is applicable to all platforms): http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

Comment: There are no memory leaks in the software as far as I can see. The memory used by the process does not go up with time in the Task Manager. The communication (TX/RX every 100 ms) can work fine all day, then the error occurs once. Nothing in the Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Okay so it runs all day without issue. It still could be an issue with VM page-pool / size. You could try increasing virtual memory, or check out the various registry hacks for tweaking this. If your disk is running IO all day it's acting like a file server which can be optimized. Also try stopping Anti-Virus.